# What is the best solution for writing numbers into file and than read them?

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

I have 640*480 numbers. I need to write them into a file. I will need to read them later. What is the best solution? Numbers are between 0 - 255.

For me the best solution is to write them binary(8 bits). I wrote the numbers into txt file and now it looks like 1011111010111110 ..... So there are no questions where the number starts and ends.

How am I supposed to read them from the file?

Using c++

Comment: How about inserting a delimiter e.g. `|` or its respective code in the middle of two numbers?

Comment: It sounds like you have an image. Why not store it as such?

Comment: It is depth of scanned area (640*480 depth of points). It is a scan from MS Kinect. I need to store this values for later use.

Comment: Best for what? Do you care most about performance, ease of debugging, data portability, operating system portability?

Comment: Best for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good idea to write bit values like 1 and 0 to text file. The file size will bigger in 8 times. 1 byte = 8 bits. You have to store bytes, 0-255 - is byte. So your file will have size 640*480 bytes instead of 640*480*8. Every symbol in text file has size of 1 byte minimum. If you want to get bits, use binary operators of programming language that you use. To read bytes much easier. Use binary file for saving your data.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am using c++. I really need to store them into file. So should I use binary file? How to read the numbers from it?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have some sort of data structure representing your image, which somewhere inside holds the actual data:

```
class pixmap
{
public:
    // stuff...
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::uint8_t[]> data;
};
```

So you can add a new constructor which takes a filename and reads bytes from that file:

```
pixmap(const std::string& filename)
{
    constexpr int SIZE = 640 * 480;

    // Open an input file stream and set it to throw exceptions:
    std::ifstream file;
    file.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit);
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    // Create a unique ptr to hold the data: this will be cleaned up
    // automatically if file reading throws
    std::unique_ptr<std::uint8_t[]> temp(new std::uint8_t[SIZE]);

    // Read SIZE bytes from the file
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(temp.get()), SIZE);

    // If we get to here, the read worked, so we move the temp data we've just read
    // into where we'd like it
    data = std::move(temp); // or std::swap(data, temp) if you prefer
}
```

I realise I've assumed some implementation details here (you might not be using a `std::unique_ptr` to store the underlying image data, though you probably should be) but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the number between 0-255 as the char value in the file.
See the below code. in this example I am printing integer 70 as char.
So this result in print as 'F' on the console.
Similarly you can read it as char and then convert this char to integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i = 70;
    char dig = (char)i;

    printf("%c", dig);

    return 0;
}
```

This way you can restrict the file size.